# How to get multiple results from the same filter with Drupal REST API?

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-9

I am using the Drupal REST API UI module to create filters I can search. I have one for a page type called Category. If I want to search for category 52 I can use this -

`api/resources/?category_id=52`

I have some scenarios where I need to populate results from different categories. So for example I want all pages with category 52 and 57 to appear. If I try this -

`api/resources/?category_id=52&category_id=57`

It only loads the results from the last filter, which is 57.

Is there any way I can get it to show results from more than 1 category?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass category id in array in your query and you want to get result from both category id then use "IN" in your query.